# Unable to deploy applications using tensorflow on heroku?

Tags: tensorflow, heroku, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-classification

I am trying to deploy a Tomato Classification Project on Heroku but when I deploy it I got error because the size of tensorflow along with other files exceeds 500 MB. I also tried using tensorflow-cpu but it does not have keras.load_model() which I need to load model.
Is tere any solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using tensorflow-2.1.0, it should work.